# Now able to click on small pop up window using selenium web-driver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on a dialog box which opens after clicking on Logout button in a website.
The role of the div tag  is dialog and it is inside an iframe.
I am not able to click on the logout button inside that opened dialog box.

I have tried switching to the iframe before clicking on that button. But not working.Still after switching when  I click on the button it gives me error.
When I call getWindowHandles() function it gives me only 1 open window.

Please help.

Comment: Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Frames are special, in general, you need to use

```
driver.switchTo().frame()
```